# How many Arithmetic Progressions having $3$ terms can be made from integers $1$ to $n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How many Arithmetic Progressions having $3$ terms can be made from integers $1$ to $n$? The numbers in the AP must be distinct.

For example if $n=6$ then number of AP's possible are $6$

- $1,2,3$
- $2,3,4$
- $3,4,5$
- $4,5,6$
- $2,4,6$

Comment: Note, you don't specifically say that the three numbers are distinct. $1,1,1$ is an arithmetic progression...

Comment: Yeah I missed that. The numbers are essentially distinct in this question.

Comment: What about 5,3,1?

Comment: @Hurkyl it is valid. We will just multiply the answer by 2 as only distinct numbers are allowed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One can select any tow distinct elements of the same parity. Together with their mean, they make such a progression.

There are $\left\lfloor \frac n2\right\rfloor$ even numbers $\le n$ and $\left\lfloor \frac{n+1}2\right\rfloor$ odd numbers.
Since we need to select unordered pairs (or ordered? But you seem not to distinguish between 1,2,3 and 3,2,1), the total number is
$$ f(n) = {\left\lfloor \frac n2\right\rfloor\choose 2}+{\left\lfloor \frac {n+1}2\right\rfloor\choose 2}.$$
If $n=2m$ is even, this amounts to 
$$ f(n) = 2{m\choose 2}=m(m-1)$$
and if $n=2m+1$ is odd, to 
$$ f(n) = {m\choose 2}+{m+1\choose 2} = m^2.$$
Both may also be summarized as
$$ f(n) = \left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor\cdot\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}2\right\rfloor.$$

*Example:* Letting $n=6$, we obtain $f(n)=\left\lfloor\frac 62\right\rfloor\cdot\left\lfloor\frac52\right\rfloor=3\cdot 2=6$.

Answer (score 3):

Let the three term AP be $a,a+d,a+2d$ where $a,d$ are natural numbers.

So, $a\ge1$ and $a+2d\le n\implies 1\le a\le n-2d \implies d\le \frac{n-1}2$

If $d=1,a$ can assume $1,2,\cdots, n-2$ i.e., $n-2$ values.

If $d=2,a$ can assume $1,2,\cdots, n-4$ i.e., $n-4$ values.

If $n$ is even, $d_{max}=\frac{n-2}2$

for $d=\frac {n-2}2,1\le a\le 2$ i.e., $a$ has 2 values.

If $n$ is even, the number of AP is $(n-2)+(n-4)+\cdots+2=\frac{(n-2)}4(2+n-2)=\frac{n(n-2)}4$

If $n$ is odd, $d_{max}=\frac{n-1}2$

So, in that case the number of AP will be $1+3+\cdots+(n-4)+(n-2)=\frac{(n-1)^2}4$

Comment: the way I have solved this question gives me the wrong answer: For even- choose 2 elements first from n/2 elements, then the third element can be found by adding the difference of the first 2 numbers. This gives: $\binom{n/2}{2}$ which i hlf the answer you get. Why is my method wrong?